# How to insert certain values to a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I want to convert

```
from = [
    [1],[2],[3],[4],
]
```

shape (4, 1)

this tensor

```
to = [
    [1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],
]
```

shape (4, 2)

this tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile), [tf.repeat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat), [tf.concat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) ***or*** [tf.stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from_tensor = tf.constant([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
to_tensor_with_tile = tf.tile(from_tensor, [1, 2])
to_tensor_with_repeat = tf.repeat(from_tensor, repeats=2, axis=1)
to_tensor_with_concat = tf.concat([from_tensor, from_tensor], axis=1)
to_tensor_with_stack = tf.squeeze(tf.stack([from_tensor, from_tensor], axis=-1), axis=1)

print(to_tensor_with_tile)
print(to_tensor_with_repeat)
print(to_tensor_with_concat)
print(to_tensor_with_stack)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]
 [4 4]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]
 [4 4]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]
 [4 4]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]
 [4 4]], shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: it's a genius solution! thank you